# How can I introduce a switch/parameter to my script?

Tags: powershell, scripting

Ok so long story/short: My boss wants me to alter this script that Iv'e been working on (and that folks here have helped with) to have a sort of 'log only' function. Run it with say a '-log' (or really whatever) and have it process like normal except only log what it would have done. And in this case I've already tried -WhatIf...not explanatory enough.

So I've added two new functions, which are copies of existing functions just with some write-log additions instead of the actual cmdlets. I think it'll be exactly what he's looking for except I have no idea how to call them.

Here's the code:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------[Initializations]-------------------------------------------------------- 
 
#  Dot Source required Function Libraries
#. "\\server\e$\scripts\Logging_Functions.ps1" 
. "c:\users\documents\powershell\Logging_Functions.ps1"

#  Error Action
$ErrorActionPreference = 'silentlycontinue'
#  Debug preference
#$global:DebugPreference = "continue"
#  WhatIf Preference, uncomment to run script in a logging only function
#$WhatIfPreference = $true

#----------------------------------------------------------[Declarations]----------------------------------------------------------
  
#  Script Version
$sScriptVersion = "1.0"

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#  Log File Info
$sLogPath = "C:\Users\Documents\powershell\Logs"
#$sLogPath = "\\server\e$\Logs"
$sLogName = "Set-LitmosGroups_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss).log"
$sLogFile = Join-Path -Path $sLogPath -ChildPath $sLogName
$LogLine = $null 


#  Variable Initializations
#  Org Unit where the target groups reside (Litmos)
$OU = "ou=test_litmos, ou=test accounts, ou=company, dc=domain, dc=net"
#  Org unt containing the All Managers security group
$OU2 = "CN=All Managers,OU=Organizational,OU=Groups,OU=company,DC=domain,DC=net"

#  Get member of the 'ALL Managers' security group
$Managers = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $OU2 | Select-Object -expandproperty samaccountname

#  Get AD groups with Report to in the name in $ou
$ReportsTo = Get-adgroup -searchbase $ou -filter "Name -like 'Report to *'" |  
Select-Object -expandproperty name

$groupcount = 0
$samecount = 0
$addcount = 0

#----------------------------------------------------------[Functions]-------------------------------------------------------------


Function Get-DirectReport {
    #requires -Module ActiveDirectory
 
    <#
.SYNOPSIS
    This script will get a user's direct reports recursively from ActiveDirectory unless specified with the NoRecurse parameter.
    It also uses the user's EmployeeID attribute as a way to exclude service accounts and/or non standard accounts that are in the reporting structure.
  
.NOTES
    Name: Get-DirectReport
    Author: theSysadminChannel
    Version: 1.0
    DateCreated: 2020-Jan-28
  
.LINK
    https://thesysadminchannel.com/get-direct-reports-in-active-directory-using-powershell-recursive -  
  
.PARAMETER SamAccountName
    Specify the samaccountname (username) to see their direct reports.
  
.PARAMETER NoRecurse
    Using this option will not drill down further than one level.
  
.EXAMPLE
    Get-DirectReport username
  
.EXAMPLE
    Get-DirectReport -SamAccountName username -NoRecurse
  
.EXAMPLE
    "username" | Get-DirectReport
#>
 
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $false,
            ValueFromPipeline = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true
        )]
 
        [string]  $SamAccountName,
 
        [switch]  $NoRecurse
    )
 
    BEGIN {}
 
    PROCESS {
        $UserAccount = Get-ADUser $SamAccountName -Properties DirectReports, DisplayName
        $UserAccount | select -ExpandProperty DirectReports | ForEach-Object {
            $User = Get-ADUser $_ -Properties DirectReports, DisplayName, Title, EmployeeID
            if ($null -ne $User.EmployeeID) {
                if (-not $NoRecurse) {
                    Get-DirectReport $User.SamAccountName
                }
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    SamAccountName    = $User.SamAccountName
                    UserPrincipalName = $User.UserPrincipalName
                    DisplayName       = $User.DisplayName
                    Manager           = $UserAccount.DisplayName
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
    END {}
 
}

Function New-bhReportToGroup {

    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)] 
    $Log1 = "New group for " + $manager + " has been created."
    $Log2 = "Group for " + $manager + " already exists."
    #From on when you see the below line $script:<variable> that sets the scope for that variable to the entire script which means other functions can use the value
    $script:ReportsTo = $ReportsTo -replace ("Report to ", "")

    if ($manager -notin $ReportsTo) { 
        new-adgroup -name "Report to $manager" -groupscope global -path $ou
        $addcount = $addcount +1
        $LogLine = $Log1
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
    else {
        $samecount = $samecount + 1
        $LogLine = $Log2
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
}

Function New-bhReportToGroup_logonly {

    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)] 
    $Log1 = "New group for " + $manager + " would have been created in $OU."
    $Log2 = "Group for " + $manager + " already exists in $OU."
    $script:ReportsTo = $ReportsTo -replace ("Report to ", "")

    if ($manager -notin $ReportsTo) { 
        $addcount = $addcount +1
        $LogLine = $Log1
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
    else {
        $samecount = $samecount + 1
        $LogLine = $Log2
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
}

Function Get-bhDReports {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)] 
    $script:directreports = Get-Directreport $manager -norecurse  | Select-Object samAccountName
    if ($null -ne $directreports) {        
        $LogLine = "Gathering direct reports for " + $manager
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
    else {
        $LogLine = $manager + " has no reports."
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }   
}

Function Set-bhRTGmembers {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)] 
    #
    #  Get manager's 'report to <manager>' group again to update members
    $managerReportToGroup = Get-ADGroup -SearchBase $OU -Filter "Name -like 'Report to $Manager'"
    if ($managerReportToGroup) {
        Add-ADGroupMember -identity $managerReportToGroup.Name -members $DirectReports
        Add-ADGroupMember -identity $managerReportToGroup.name -members $Manager
        $LogLine = "Report to " + $Manager + " updated."
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
    else {
        $LogLine = "Could not find group for " + $Manager
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
}

Function Set-bhRTGmembers_logonly {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)] 
    #
    #  Get manager's 'report to <manager>' group again to update members
    $managerReportToGroup = Get-ADGroup -SearchBase $OU -Filter "Name -like 'Report to $Manager'"
    if ($managerReportToGroup) {
        $LogLine = "Report to " + $Manager + " would be updated with $DirectReports."
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
    else {
        $LogLine = "Could not find group for " + $Manager
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
}

#----------------------------------------------[ Execution ]------------------------------------------------
Foreach ($Manager in $Managers) {
    New-bhReportToGroup
    Get-bhDReports
    Set-bhRTGmembers
}

Foreach ($Report in $ReportsTo) {
    $report = $report -replace ("Report to ", "")
    if ($Report -notin $managers) {
        Remove-ADGroup -Identity "Report to $Report" -confirm:$false
        $LogLine = $report + " user has fell out of scope, Report group removed."
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine
    }
    else {
        $LogLine = "No groups deleted.`n"
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
}
#Remove-Variable * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue; Remove-Module *; $error.Clear(); Clear-Host
```

You can see the '_logonly' functions.. how can I call them from a cmdline with a switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a `[Switch]$LogOnly` parameter to each, and then surround the "work" with an if statement like this:

Before:

```
#do the work
#do the logging
```

After:

```
if(-not $LogOnly){
  #Do the work
}
#Do the logging
```

Comment: You are meaning the Execution section yes?

Comment: if (-not $Logonly){
Foreach ($Manager in $Managers) {
    New-bhReportToGroup
    Get-bhDReports
    Set-bhRTGmembers
} else {
    Foreach ($Manager in $Managers){
        New-bhReportToGroup_logonly
        Get-bhDReports
        Set-bhRTGmembers_logonly
    }
}

}

Comment: @skeer - I meant to do this wherever there's something you want to skip ("the work") whenever you're in "LogOnly" mode.  For example, the Add-ADGroupMember calls in Set-bhRTGmembers or the Remove-ADGroup call in the execution section.

Comment: I can be a little slow on the uptake but this is working super!  Thank you!

Comment: Actually, I hope you read this) but the code you suggested is half working. I formatted it like: if(-not $Logonly){ blah blah } else { blah blah logonly } and the Else portion is not being hit. It's ignored fully.

Comment: Did you add the switch parameter (in a param statement) at the top of your code?

Comment: Yeah I did.. I've got it at the top like so: Param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][Switch]$Logonly) If my execution section contains: if (-not $Logonly){ every instance runs as if logonly was the switch even when it wasn't. I tried if ($logonly -eq $false) { but it runs as if the switch is not present even when it is.